# Google Earth Engine : define polygon Labels for assets

Tags: labeling, google-earth-engine

I'm using the importation assets option to import my shapefile into GEE.
Everything is fine, but I would like to modify the labels of my regions.
My graphs don't have the proper label, and for a table exported with more than 50 regions I don't to do it manually.
For a `ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-122.45, 37.74, -122.4, 37.8), {label: 'City'})`it is straightforward. But I don't know how to do it for a shapefile.

Here is a description of my shapefile once imported:

```
type: 
FeatureCollection
id: 
************/*****************/*************
version: 
1518788242243348
columns: 
Object (4 properties)
NAME_0: 
String
NAME_1: 
String
NAME_2: 
String
system:index: 
String
properties: 
Object (1 property)
system:asset_size: 
301487
```

Comment: may be you should read this before: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/feature_collection_mapping

Comment: A FeatureCollection generated from a shapefile is no different than any other FeatureCollection. What have you tried so far?